# java set a timer - daily morning and evening

Tags: java, timer, intervals

I need to run a method at daily morning at 8 and evening at 8, for this thinking to do with Java timer. how to set timer for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Timer class.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), calendar.getTime());

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

       public void run() {
       } 
    }
```

On similar lines you can create another timer for evening time also. Another option is to use the single timer where the start time is morning 8 and interval is 12 hours.

You may also use other libraries for scheduling like [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of libraries that will do what you want, look at [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the time periodically using a function like this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class currentTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
    }

}
```

So have a counter and run it every x number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule TimerTask to run at the top of every hour and check if it is 8 with the help of Calendar

```
    long hour = 3600 * 1000;
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR) == 8) {
                // run
            }
        }
    }, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() / hour * hour), hour);
```

it will run at 8 even after switching to summer time